# Merge [attr] and [attributes]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) doesn't add anything over [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes) (only that it’s jQuery specific). Let's merge [attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) into [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes). I can't suggest a synonym.

Current description for [attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr):

> This tag should be used for attribute related issues.
> An attribute is a specification that defines a property of an object, element, or file. It may also refer to or set the specific value for a given instance of such.

Current description for [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes) is much longer, but the first parts look very similar to [attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr)’s:

> The attributes tag should be used for any issues relating to a property of an object, element, or file, etc.
> In computing, an attribute is a specification that defines a property of an object, element, or file. It may also refer to or set the specific value for a given instance of such.

Comment: Strange it is not like [prop](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prop/info)

Comment: I guess you've enough reputation for suggesting tag synonym? And I think it should be done here.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that "merging" tags is a *good* idea.

Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216593/233438) and read the answer by Gilles there.

The OP wanted the tags [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exist) and [existdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existdb) to be merged; however, if you merge both into the desired tag of [existdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existdb), some other user at a later point in time will try to create the ambiguous tag, [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exist) again.

Since you want [attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) to be merged into [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribute), I believe you should simply leave a note in the [attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) tag such as "Please use [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribute) instead". This is like using the `@Deprecated` annotation in `Java`.